# Adding Column name and value as variables in Qtsql PyQT4

Tags: python, sql, pyqt4

I am trying to add values to SQL database table. But I want to use the column name and the value as variables. The Python console shows no errors with this code. But no change in the database table. Means there is no insertion happens. I am using Python , PyQt4, and SQLite3. Is there any way to do this.

```
nameentry = "John Doe"
columnName = "Name"

self.query.exec('''INSERT INTO MainTable {cn} VALUES {dv};'''.format(cn=tuple(columnName),dv=tuple(nameentry)))
```

I searched everywhere. But I didn't get an answer.
This is my Table
[Simple Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EjFj.jpg)

Comment: OK. What is the error you are currently getting? Please provide details.

Comment: No error in Python Console. But in database table shows no addition of this entry. means no insertion happens

Comment: Add that detail to your question please.

Comment: @idjaw I am using Python PyQt4 and SQLite3. I will add that too..

Answer (score 0):

Your query string is complete garbage:

```
>>> nameentry = "John Doe"
>>> columnName = "Name"
>>> '''INSERT INTO MainTable {cn} VALUES {dv};'''.format(cn=tuple(columnName),dv=tuple(nameentry))
"INSERT INTO MainTable ('N', 'a', 'm', 'e') VALUES ('J', 'o', 'h', 'n', ' ', 'D', 'o', 'e');"
```

Perhaps you meant something more like:

```
>>> '''INSERT INTO MainTable {cn} VALUES {dv};'''.format(cn=columnName,dv=(nameentry,))
"INSERT INTO MainTable Name VALUES ('John Doe',);"
```

But I'm not sure that will work either, since there's a trailing comma in the values. So you might have to try this instead:

```
>>> '''INSERT INTO MainTable {cn} VALUES ({dv!r}) ;'''.format(cn=columnName,dv=nameentry)
"INSERT INTO MainTable Name VALUES ('John Doe') ;"
```

Comment: @ekhumoroThat doesn't work either..I don't know why. http://i.stack.imgur.com/1EjFj.jpg This is my table

Comment: @ameen. You need to provide real **code**, not pictures.

Comment: I am adding columns dynamically with codes...  `self.query.exec_("ALTER TABLE MainTable ADD {cn} {dt} ".format(cn=column_name, dt=data_type))`  ..It works.. But when I add this code which is direct without variables           @ekhumoro          `self.query.exec_("INSERT INTO MainTable Name VALUES ('JOHN JOE');")  `            it doesn't work..

Comment: It is a little big program. How can I share all these codes?

Comment: Yeah got it.I have to insert the ID number. When I wrote like this, it works.. `self.query.exec_("INSERT INTO MainTable (ID, Name)VALUES (5,'JOHN JOE');")`